# Calculating Integer Percentage

Tags: c#, math, percentage

So I would like to calculate the percentage progress of my program as the nearest integer value

In my examples lets take

```
int FilesProcessed = 42;
int TotalFilesToProcess = 153;
```

So First I tried:

```
Int TotalProgress = ((FilesProcessed / TotalFilesToProcess) * 100)
```

This returned `TotalProgress = 0`

Then I tried

```
Int TotalProgress = (int)((FilesProcessed / TotalFilesToProcess) * 100)
```

This gives compiler error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type decimal to int`

Ive tried

```
Int TotalProgress = Math.Round((FilesProcessed / TotalFilesToProcess) * 100)
```

and get `The call is ambiguous between decimal and double`

and so now I've come here for help?

Comment: What types are `FilesProcessed` and `TotalFilesToProcess`?

Comment: or multiply by 100 than divide by `TotalFiles`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Cast to `double` first so it doesn't compute a division between `integers`:

```
int totalProgress = (int)((double)FilesProcessed / TotalFilesToProcess * 100);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
int FilesProcessed = 42;
int TotalFilesToProcess = 153;
int TotalProgress = FilesProcessed * 100 / TotalFilesToProcess;

Console.WriteLine(TotalProgress);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3GNlVd

Comment: this will throw exception when total is 0

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be more accuracy, you can use:

```
int TotalProgress = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(((decimal)FilesProcessed / TotalFilesToProcess) * 100, 0));
```

If the numbers are greater you will have a difference. For example

```
int FilesProcessed = 42;
int TotalFilesToProcess = 1530;
```

The result with decimals will be: 2.74%, if you use the previous methods, you would find 2%, with the formula I am proposing you will obtain 3%. The last option has more accuracy.